# How many '7' in a range from '1' to '100'

Tags: combinatorics

This question appears on my daughter's Mathematics class in secondary school:

"There are 100 rooms in a hotel. Joe must number the rooms from 1 to 100 with
 plastic digits. How many times does he need the digit 7?"

My answer is:
07
17
27
37
47
57
67
77
87
97

Number 7 will appear 11 times.
However, the book's answer on the back is: 20 times 
Can you explain why??

Comment: $70, 71, 72, \cdots , 79$

Comment: OMG! You right. I feel sooo stupid now. How I could omit them?

Comment: We can close this topic now I guess. thanks a lot.

Comment: Probably not a hard problem, but definitely a great father.

Answer (score 3):

07,17,27,37,47,57,67,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,77,78,79,87,97

Answer (score 1):

7,17,27,37,47,57,67,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,87,97
So the answer is 20

(previous answer said 19, probably omitting the two 7s that are present in '77')